# Add new row using footer template and textarea with cleditor as input

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I'm adding new row in gridview using footertemplate. In footertemplate I have html textarea binded with cleditor. once I enter the text in textarea and enter add button then that entered text got cleared.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use asp textbox instead of textarea

change your html textarea with something like this

```
<asp:TextBox id="input" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

**don't forget TextMode="MultiLine"

and your cleditor declaration should be something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= input.ClientId %>').cleditor({width:500, height:180, useCSS:true});
});
```